# Thread Pool using Executor Framrwork

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am using an the executor framework to create multiple instances of the Fadder object and print the result. I am trying to learn how to use multiple threads to get a task done faster. The problem I am having is that the numbers print in a random order each time I run the program. I thought creating a new object for each iteration of the loop would solve that problem but it still prints the number in a "random" order. Is there any way I can guarantee that the threads print in the order they are suppose to run? like 1,2,3,4,5. Thanks

```
package fadder;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Fadder {
    private final int n;
    Fadder(int n){
        //initialize Fadder
        this.n = n;
    }
    Fadder add(int m){
        //create new Fadder
        return new Fadder(n+m);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int threadnum = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadnum);
        Fadder MyAdder = new Fadder(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i+=1 ) {
            int index = i;
            //lambda function to print Fadder
        executor.submit(() -> {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(MyAdder.add(index)));
                });
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes : change your first line to `int threadnum = 1;` - honestly, please read up on threads - the whole point is that they can do things in parallel, each at their own speed. If you want to print number in sequential order, then you should not be using threads. Using threads for this does not make it faster. If calculating the number takes a lot of time, then threads could make sense, you can do calculations in separate threads, collect all the results into a collection and then sort them.

Comment: Fadder doesn't have a `toString` method, how do you know what order they run in?

Comment: Thanks Erwin, I knew about threadnum = 1, but this was kind of just a test to see if I could get it work the way I wanted for a larger program.

Comment: @immibis I had a toString method but it was made redundant by the String.valueOf function.

Comment: @Art String.valueOf calls the object's toString function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot garantee the sequence in which many threads will process your code.
But, will parallel stream, you can. See below :

```
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(1, i->i+1).limit(5) ;
      stream.parallel().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```